# Can't load images when using a web-based text editor like summernote loaded inside a WebView #javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine, javafx-webview

Can't load images or any files when using a Web-based text editor like [summernote](https://summernote.org/)  loaded inside a WebView #javafx.

I noticed that loading images/files works fine when I open summernote.html file on my browser, but when I try it inside a WebView {embedded in my project}, images/files fails to load in the editor.

[image]

texteditor.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>


<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="patient.froala.TextEditorController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="wv_texteditor" minHeight="300.0" minWidth="992.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Controller file

```
package patient.summernote;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TextEditorController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private WebView wv_texteditor;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        Platform.runLater((()->{
            WebEngine webEngine=wv_texteditor.getEngine();
            webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("summernote.html").toExternalForm());

        }));
    }
}
```

summernote.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
    <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- include summernote css/js -->
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error after hours of testing .

Code 4 FileReader :
The file or directory cannot be read, typically due to permission problems that occur after a reference to a file has been acquired (for example, the file or directory is concurrently locked by another application).

so I used java to access files from the local filesystem. having the file then passing it to the summernote through the (javascript-java) bridge offered by the WebView ,I managed to insert images . [image]

```
btn_insertimg.setOnAction(event->{
                            File file=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(webview.getScene().getWindow());
                            if(file==null)
                                return;
                            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                            String string= "file:\\" + file.getAbsolutePath();
                            //as the script eats the single backslash we should double it
                            //before doubling file:\C:\Users\Muhammad\Pictures\Army\1.jpg
                            //after doubling  file:\\C:\\Users\\Muhammad\\Pictures\\Army\\1.jpg
                            //without doubling file:C:UsersMuhammadPicturesArmy.jpg
                            string=string.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\");
                            System.out.println(string);
                            webEngine.executeScript("insertImg('"+string+"','1.jpg')");
                        });
```